# Visiting Monaco as an EU citizen -- what to think about?

Tags: insurance, eu, eu-citizens, monaco

I've never been outside of EU, so I could really use some advice before I put myself in a bad situation. I'm thinking about going to Monaco for vacation for a couple of days at the end of June. If this was an EU trip, I'd simply book train/plane tickets, book a hostel and be done with it.

Monaco *is* included in the Schengen agreement, so I suppose I won't need a visa, but what about things like health insurance? Is my EHIC good there?

Basically: What to think about?

Further, if I travelled to France somewhere close to the border, could I simply take the train to Monaco, or would the process be more involved?

Comment: Monaco [has been closely integrated with France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France%E2%80%93Monaco_relations) even before the Schengen agreement or, in fact, the EU. Crossing the border is very easy, staying in France would be fine. That and Monaco is very small anyway. I would rather go to Nice or Italy and make a day trip to Monaco than spend a few days there.

Comment: Monaco is a fiscal paradise, so they let you in with pleasure as long as you spend money out there. The only place to visit is the Ocean Museum, oh, and also the Dolls Museum.
Don't worry, they are very rich and will take care of you if you have an health issue (it's not USA here, nor jungle).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you say, Monaco is part of Schengen Area, which means there are no internal border controls between Monaco and its only neighbour (France). So you *certainly* do not need a visa. No one's even going to look at your passport. Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area):

> Monaco has an open border with France. Schengen laws are administered
>   as if it were a part of France [...]

I'm not sure about EHIC. But you have some sort of **travel insurance** from your home country, don't you? If you do, it very likely is valid in Monaco too. If you don't (and you travel), consider getting one.

**Edit**: UK's Foreign & Commonwealth Office has a [Monaco info page](http://www.fco.gov.uk/en/travel-and-living-abroad/travel-advice-by-country/europe/monaco) that directly answers that part of your question (emphasis mine):

> Monaco is not a Member of the European Union and therefore EU
>   reciprocal medical arrangements do not apply. The **European Health
>   Insurance Card (EHIC) does not provide health cover in Monaco**. It is
>   essential that you have comprehensive travel and medical insurance
>   cover.

So do get a travel insurance. Other than that, there is nothing about going to Monaco you should especially worry about, even if you'll technically be outside EU.

Regarding your final question about **getting to Monaco**: it is easy and there are lots of options, as e.g. [Wikitravel will tell you](http://wikitravel.org/en/Monaco#Get_in). For instance, you could take a train from Nice, Cannes, Menton (France) or Ventimiglia (Italy). Or [take bus 100 from Nice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/11067/583), which I can recommend: it takes a lovely seaside route and costs just 1 €.

(If still in doubt, you should ask more specific questions about getting to Monaco from a given place!)

Answer (score 4):

I doubt anything changed since the last time I visited, but I'd say there's little you have to worry about. Crossing the border is not even a formality. You can just walk/bus/drive/train in.

I'm not familiar with EHIC, but they don't claim to cover you in Monaco:

http://www.fco.gov.uk/en/travel-and-living-abroad/staying-safe/travel-insurance/ehic

I suppose you need to get a travel insurance to cover that.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about health insurance, but I was in Monaco a few years ago. There is no border. You just go there. I went walking around and eventually it got a bit boring, so I turned around and walked back the way I came, and saw a "Welcome to Monaco" sign. Apparently I had walked out of Monaco and into France without noticing and without any "Welcome to France" signs.

Comment: yup. Was that way even back in the 1980s.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding EHIC in Monaco, don't worry too much. Monaco is very small, so if you don't do any high-risk activities, you won't need to have medical help there – France is a few kilometres away with EHIC coverage, and has an open border with Monaco; even in rush conditions you'll be able to get there and go to the Nice or Menton hospitals.

Plus, regarding Monaco's hospital (the only reasonable reason you would get treated in Monaco being an emergency where someone brings your there), [this page describes things related to health coverage](http://www.chpg.mc/fr/patient-famille/hospitalisation/preparer-votre-venue/votre-admission/formalites):

- If you're covered in France…

  - in the Alpes maritimes: you're covered;
  - elsewhere in France: emergencies (only) are covered.
- If you're covered in Italy, if you have the "MIC8" form (that the USL of your constituency can give you), you're covered for emergencies; else, they'll check with their local health insurance (Caisse de Compensation des Services Sociaux).
- If you're covered elsewhere in Europe, you might get coverage depending on your situation at the admission and their discussion with the French health insurance.

Be aware that some mutual insurance / supplementary insurance companies do not cover Monaco.

Comment: This is bad advice. If you get (for example) hit by a car in Monaco, you could well find yourself being treated in Monaco. I've seen this happen. If you're not covered in Monaco, that could leave you with a hefty bill.

Comment: This really depends on cost vs. risk. I'm not aware of how much travel insurance costs for Monaco but it may be costly too. And seriously, all travelers to Monaco I know of do not take travel insurance just for a few hours/days in Monaco, with France at most at 1 km. But YMMV.