# Stop for bus 100 Nice/Monaco

Tags: buses, nice, monaco

What is the address at Le Port where I pick up Bus 100 to ride to Monaco from Nice?  Wife is slightly handicapped so I don't want to have to walk a lot to find the bus stop.

Comment: Very closely related (as in there's a map in the first answer, assuming it is still current information, which a user reports it was last November): http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11066/how-to-get-from-nice-to-monaco-by-public-transport